# What are JavaScript Data Types?

Tags: javascript

What are JavaScript Data Types?

Comment: Why this question was voted down?

Comment: Yonita, what do you mean? Are you looking for a list of the data types offered by JavaScript, or do you want to know what the word "datatype" means?

Comment: I'm sure the question was voted down because it is very unclear what she's asking.

Comment: Unclear? I guess it's pretty straightforward - @Ennovy is asking the data types available for JavaScript. This is a real question.

Comment: see this: http://symfony-world.blogspot.com/2013/07/javascript-datatypes.html

Comment: This _is_ a real question. Clear and up to the point as it could possibly be.

Comment: This  [JavaScript data types and data structures](https://youtu.be/AsJhjDirCUI) video  might be helpful.

Comment: The question is clear and proper. Please vote to reopen

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's

- Numbers
- Strings
- Booleans
- Objects
- null
- undefined

Note that there isn't a separate Integer, just number - which is represented as a double precision floating point number.

There's also

- Functions
- Arrays
- RegExps

all of which are Objects deep down, but with enough special wiring to be mentioned on their own.

Comment: And there are special-purpose objects like Dates.

Comment: Good point, Peter Bailey--functions are objects.

Comment: Functions are Objects in JavaScript, but yeah.

Comment: @Nosredna & @Magnar - Unless I'm sorely mistaken, no they aren't: `alert( typeof function(){} )` vs `alert( typeof {} )`

Comment: Keep in mind that `null` is always reported as `Object` when passed into the `typeof` function.

Comment: According to http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html everything apart from numbers, strings and booleans are objects. They do behave differently enough that they might aswell be listed as a separate datatype. Fixing.

Comment: @Peter Bailey. It depends. JavaScript is notorious poor at reflection of its types. I wouldn't go by what it _says_ its types are.

Comment: Arrays are Objects too.. I feel this slope is getting slippery.. should we add Dates and RegExp too now? No, they're objects. I'm about to change my mind on functions again. ;-)

Comment: Arrays definitely have their own place in the language. They are objects, but there's a lot of extra rigging built around them. The real answer is that with JavaScript, answers are almost always mushy. Good answers are always followed up with "yes, but" clauses. It's a very flexible language. A shapeshifter, ready to throw on a blonde wig and party dress any night of the week.

Comment: Are objects considered primitive types?

Comment: Would NaN also be considered as a type?

Answer (score 17):

There are five primitive data types in JavaScript:

1. number
2. string
3. boolean
4. undefined
5. null

Everything that is not a primitive is an object.

Comment: Isn't null an empty object used to initialize object that don't have values? Why is it still considered a primitive type? -- sorry noob here

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has a `typeof` operator that returns a string that names the datatype of its argument.  So, you could say that the datatypes in Javascript are all the possible return values of this operator.  Look here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof