# Reference : TypeError: Cannot read property [property name here] from undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, typeerror, undefined

Derived from [Canonical question for TypeError Cannot [call method / read property / set property] of null in Google Apps Script](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420764/1595451)

---

Proposed reference for questions like :

- Why the [Execution order of GS files in a Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687907/execution-order-of-gs-files-in-a-project) causes `TypeError: Cannot read property "sayName" from undefined.`?
- [Testing a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089041/1595451) causes `ReferenceError: 'e' is not defined.` or `TypeError: Cannot read property *...* from undefined`
- [TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18947556/1595451)
- [Google Script send form values by email, error: cannot read property "namedValues"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28997714/1595451)
  <sup>Not enough details from the OP but three different answers that for different scenarios</sup>
- [TypeError: Cannot call method "getName" of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43917978/1595451)
- [TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined (line 3, file "Code"). I have a trigger for on form submit and yet it still has an error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74104563/1595451)<sup>Missing character in property name (OP used value instead of values)</sup>

Comment: This question was posted after discussion on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

The error message indicates that you are trying to access a property on an `Object` instance, but during *runtime* the value *actually* held by a variable is a special data type `undefined`.

<sup>See key terms definition at the bottom.</sup>

#### Causes:

- The error occurs when accessing **properties of an object, which does not exist**.

  If a property doesn't exist in a object, accessing that property results in undefined and eventually a type error, if undefined is accessed like a real object.. This maybe due to typos or  using case insensitive names to access a property. A variation of this error with a numeric value in place of property name indicates that an instance of `Array` was expected. As arrays in JavaScript are [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), everything mentioned here is true about them as well.

```
const obj = {a:1};
const b = obj.b;//undefined because b isn't available on obj. But doesn't throw a error
console.log(b.toString())//Throws type error
```

- Accessing **Arrays index greater than the last element's index**

  Array.prototype.length returns the number of elements of the Array. This number is always greater than the last element's index, as JavaScript uses 0 based indices. Accessing any index greater than or equal to the length of the array results in  this type error. Eg, when accessing 3rd element in a array of length `3`,

```
const a = [[1],[2],[3]];
const getElement3 = a[3];//undefined,because `3`'s index is ``2`` not `3`;But doesn't throw a error
console.log(getElement3[0])//Throws type error
```

- Accessing **Event objects without a event**:

  There is a special case of *dynamically constructed* objects such as [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) that are only available in specific contexts like making an HTTP request to the app or invoking a function via time or event-based trigger.

> The error is a [TypeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) because an `"object"` is expected, but `"undefined"` is received

#### How to fix

1. **Using default values**
   [Nullish Coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) `??` operator in JavaScript evaluates the right-hand side if the left-hand is `null` or `undefined`. An expression like `(myVar ?? {}).myProp` (or `(myVar ?? [])[index]` for arrays) will guarantee that no error is thrown, if the property is at least `undefined`.

   One can also provide default values: `(myVar ?? { myProp : 2 })` guarantees accessing `myProp` to return `2` by default. Same goes for arrays: `(myVar ?? [1,2,3])`.
2. **Checking for type**
   Especially true for the special case,  `typeof` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) combined with an `if` [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) and a [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) will either allow a function to run outside of its designated context (i.e. for debugging purposes) or introduce branching logic depending on whether the object is present or not.

   One can control how strict the check should be:

   - lax ("not undefined"): `if(typeof myVar !== "undefined") { //do something; }`
   - strict ("proper objects only"): `if(typeof myVar === "object" && myVar) { //do stuff }`

#### Key Terms

Object

It's one of the JavaScript [data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type).

undefined

It's one of the JavaScript [primitive data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type).

To learn about the very basics of JavaScript data types and objects see [What are JavaScript Data Types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1288594) and [What exactly is an object? [JavaScript]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55820132).

---

<sub>Original revision extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62336083) (Credit to [@OlegValter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter-is-with-ukraine))</sub>