# To Do List - Google Script TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source') at addTimeStamp(Code:6:25)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, task

[To Do List Task List](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OIvICCTsDJcpWgKhoV7FTMBSun1Ca6Bkm7o-5_XAyfw/edit#gid=0) Google Sheet / Script Access Link

1. function onEdit  ---> The problem with log not being generated (no error)
2. function 'addTimeStamp' ---> The problem with log failed returned Type Error
3. What I want is, When the value in colD (CheckBox=True), the setValue (dateTimeStamp) to push in ColG of each row

Using onEdit for checkbox=true (Col D : Row 6) onward down, the offset to 3 right column (G5) should return the new date() as set value for the checked row. This returns no error and execution fails

function onEdit returns without any log or error (Console log) but the 'datetimestamp' is not pushed or added in  the expected col G6, g7, g8 ... etc upon check box (True)

function addTimeStamp returns error "**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')
at addTimeStamp(Code:6:25)**"

```
function onEdit(e) {
  addTimeStamp(e)
}

function addTimeStamp(e) {
  const activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  const modifiedCell = e.range
  
  const tf = activeSheet.createTextFinder("Done")             // Find text in sheet for activerange
  tf.matchEntireCell(true)
  const cellDone = tf.findNext()
  const row = cellDone.getRow()
  const col = cellDone.getColumn()

  // console.log(row)
  // console.log(col)

    if(!(modifiedCell.getColumn() === col && modifiedCell.getRow() > row)) return       // guarded statement
    // console.log("I am here")
      console.log(e.value)
    
    if(e.value === "TRUE") {
      modifiedCell.offset(0,3).setValue(new Date())
      console.log(modifiedCell.value)
      console.log(setValue)
    }  

  // SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().createTextFinder().findNext()
  // SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().offset().setValue()
}
```

Comment: About your error of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source') at addTimeStamp`, how did you run your script? In your script, it is required to use the event object. For example, is this thread useful? [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74109026)

Comment: @Tanaike Nonetheless useful!
Not only this script, in various script we found the same issues where 'e.source'  and 'e.range' always creates a problem. 
Hope the issue is not releated to any deprecated version of the snippet. I would be grate ful if you pls check the same at your end

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, if you directly ran your script with the script editor, please edit a cell of the Spreadsheet. By this, the script is run by giving the event object `e` of `onEdit(e)` as the simple trigger.

Comment: @Tanaike, - Surely we have been editing in sheet each time before running the script, but error (https://prnt.sc/LsUE-Ixj_0JW). Please, have the access link provided for public (GoggleSheet - To do List) and verify the same sheet at your end. If you have no access to the sheet please let me know testlpcp@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue. Can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: The Sheet (https://prnt.sc/lmNIncC9vNzW) having col D (on Check) the value for 'new Date()' to output in Col G (completed on). Upon check this fails to return the 'datetimestamp' in out put col G error (prnt.sc/LsUE-Ixj_0JW). in the script (https://prnt.sc/qMS93f3FRd4c)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand the method for correctly replicating your current issue of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')`. Unfortunately, when I tested your script using your provided Spreadsheet, no error occurred. I apologize for this. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

createTextFinder("Done") will find cell A1 before if finds cell D5.

See screenshot:

[image]

Change the text in cell A1 to something else, just like in the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input for my silly unnoticed issue

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as the Accepted answer.