# JavaScript error in posting to calendar on form submit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use Google Apps Scripts to post an event to a calendar upon form submit.

I tried using this code, but when I submit a form entry, no calendar event posts.

```
function createCalendarEventOnFormSubmit(e) {
  try {
    // Replace with your Calendar ID
    let calendarId = "6eidr8u1ufcj37nu27o8dm31q8@group.calendar.google.com";
    let subCalendar = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarById(calendarId);

    let sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    let schedule = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    schedule.splice(0, 2);

    schedule.forEach(function (entry) {
      let title = entry[11]; // Assuming column 12 contains the event title
      let date = entry[3];  // Assuming column 4 contains the event date and time

      // Create the event
      subCalendar.createAllDayEvent(title, new Date(date));

      // Log the event created
      console.log("Event created:", title, date);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // Log any errors that occur
    console.error("Error creating calendar event:", error);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't understand the detail of `but it's not working`. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: But it’s not working is not a question

Comment: I have a google form our teachers fill out when they are going to be absent. Responses post to a corresponding ss, and on the spreadsheet apps script, I entered this code (edited using chatGPT when the original code would post calendar events, but post them multiple times every time I ran the script and not on form submit). Column 12 has the title of the event, and column 4 has the date, in the MM/DD/YYYY format. But when I fill out the form to test the script, nothing gets posted to the calendar.

Comment: If I run the script, I get this error:  Error creating calendar event: [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')]

Comment: About your error of `If I run the script, I get this error: Error creating calendar event: [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')] `, how did you run your script? In your script, it is required to use the event object. For example, is this thread useful? [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74109026)

Comment: The error you mentioned indicates that the parameter `e` is undefined.  How is this function being called?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  let subCalendar = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarById("calendarid");
  let title = e.values[1];
  subCalendar.createAllDayEvent(title, new Date(e.values[2]));
}
```

I just use two short answer question first answer was Title and the Second one was a date